# Jmeter result configuration to use grafana

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have a transaction controller and in that 5 requests are there. Now when i run a load test and in my script "Generate parent sampler" is checked. So here what is happening is whenever a failure occurs in any of the requests within this sampler, the transaction controller shows a message like "None" or "Number of sampler" etc.

I am using Grafana to monitor my test results, so how can i show the failed response message of a failed request to a transaction controller first and then show the message in grafana

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) doesn't send response message to Grafana, you can see the possible values in the [Metrics Exposed](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) chapter.

The only way to send the response message to Grafana is changing Transaction Controller label using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://%09SampleResult.setIgnore()%20%09%20%09def%20failure%20=%20prev.getParent().getSubResults().find%20%7B%20subResullt%20-%3E%20!subResullt.isSuccessful()%20%7D%20%09%20%09if%20(failure%20!=%20null)%20%7B%20%09%20%20%20%20failure.getParent().setSampleLabel(failure.getParent().getSampleLabel()%20+%20%27:%20%27%20+%20failure.getResponseMessage())%20%09%7D).

Example code for the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()

def failure = prev.getParent().getSubResults().find { subResullt -> !subResullt.isSuccessful() }

if (failure != null) {
    failure.getParent().setSampleLabel(failure.getParent().getSampleLabel() + ': ' + failure.getResponseMessage())
}
```

Demo:

[image]